# How to save selected paths from open file dialog control

Tags: powershell

As you can see in my code, after executing it i'm able to select a Backup directory from open dialog, and a destination folder for the backup. My intention is to put the script into group policy editor, so the script will be executed after every shutdown. The problem is that the openfolder dialog opens every time i rerun the script. How i can save now my selected Backupfolder and destination Path, in order to not set them again after re-running the script?

Here is the code

```
function Find-Folders {
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog -Property @{
    SelectedPath = 'C:\Program Files\Planmeca\Romexis\client\cephmodule\analyses'
}
[void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
$FolderBrowser.SelectedPath 


$browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$browse.SelectedPath = "C:\"
$browse.ShowNewFolderButton = $true
$browse.Description = "Speicherort fuer Backup waehlen"

$loop = $true
while($loop)
{
    if ($browse.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
    $loop = $false



$Destination= $browse.SelectedPath #KOPIERE DIE DATEN --> ZIELPFAD
$Versions="3" #WIEVIEL BACKUPS SOLLEN BEHALTEN WERDEN
$BackupDirs= $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath #WELCHER ORDNER SOLL GESICHERT WERDEN
$Log="Log.txt" #Log Name
$LoggingLevel="1" #LoggingLevel only for Output in Powershell Window, 1=smart, 3=Heavy


#STOP-AB HIER KEINE AENDERUNGEN DURCHFUEHREN
#STOP-AB HIER KEINE AENDERUNGEN DURCHFUEHREN
#Settings - AB HIER KEINE AENDERUNGEN DURCHFUEHREN
$Backupdir=$Destination +"\Backup-"+ (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd)+"-"+(Get-Random -Maximum 100000)+"\"
$Items=0
$Count=0
$ErrorCount=0
$StartDate=Get-Date #-format dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss

#FUNCTION
#Logging
Function Logging ($State, $Message) {
$Datum=Get-Date -format dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss

if (!(Test-Path -Path $Log)) {
    New-Item -Path $Log -ItemType File | Out-Null
}
$Text="$Datum - $State"+":"+" $Message"

if ($LoggingLevel -eq "1" -and $Message -notmatch "was copied") {Write-Host $Text}
elseif ($LoggingLevel -eq "3" -and $Message -match "was copied") {Write-Host $Text}

add-Content -Path $Log -Value $Text
}
Logging "INFO" "----------------------"
Logging "INFO" "Start the Script"

#Create Backupdir
Function Create-Backupdir {
Logging "INFO" "Create Backupdir $Backupdir"
New-Item -Path $Backupdir -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

Logging "INFO" "Move Log file to $Backupdir"
Move-Item -Path $Log -Destination $Backupdir

Set-Location $Backupdir
Logging "INFO" "Continue with Log File at $Backupdir"
}

#Loeschen von Backupdir
Function Delete-Backupdir {
$Folder=Get-ChildItem $Destination | where {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"} | Sort-Object -Property $_.LastWriteTime -Descending:$false | Select-Object -First 1

Logging "INFO" "Remove Dir: $Folder"

$Folder.FullName | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force 
}

#Pruefe ob der Backupordner und der Zielpfad erreichbar bzw. verfügbar ist
function Check-Dir {
Logging "INFO" "Check if BackupDir and Destination exists"
if (!(Test-Path $BackupDirs)) {
    return $false
    Logging "Error" "$BackupDirs does not exist"
}
if (!(Test-Path $Destination)) {
    return $false
    Logging "Error" "$Destination does not exist"
  }
}

#Daten speichern
Function Make-Backup {
Logging "INFO" "Started the Backup"
$Files=@()
$SumMB=1
$SumItems=0
$SumCount=0
$colItems=0
Logging "INFO" "Count all files and create the Top Level Directories"

foreach ($Backup in $BackupDirs) {
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $Backup -recurse | Where-Object {$_.mode -notmatch "h"} | Measure-Object -property length -sum) 
    $Items=0
    $FilesCount = @()
    $FilesCount += Get-ChildItem $Backup -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.mode -notmatch "h"}  
    Copy-Item -Path $Backup -Destination $Backupdir -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $SumMB+=$colItems.Sum.ToString()
    $SumItems+=$colItems.Count
}

$TotalMB="{0:N2}" -f ($SumMB / 1MB) + " MB of Files"
Logging "INFO" "There are $SumItems Files with  $TotalMB to copy"

foreach ($Backup in $BackupDirs) {
    $Index=$Backup.LastIndexOf("\")
    $SplitBackup=$Backup.substring(0,$Index)
    $Files = Get-ChildItem $Backup -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.mode -notmatch "h"} 
    foreach ($File in $Files) {
        $restpath = $file.fullname.replace($SplitBackup,"")
        try {
            Copy-Item  $file.fullname $($Backupdir+$restpath) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Out-Null
            Logging "INFO" "$file was copied"
        }
        catch {
            $ErrorCount++
            Logging "ERROR" "$file returned an error an was not copied"
        }
        $Items += (Get-item $file.fullname).Length
        $status = "Copy file {0} of {1} and copied {3} MB of {4} MB: {2}" -f $count,$SumItems,$file.Name,("{0:N2}" -f ($Items / 1MB)).ToString(),("{0:N2}" -f ($SumMB / 1MB)).ToString()
        $Index=[array]::IndexOf($BackupDirs,$Backup)+1
        $Text="Copy data Location {0} of {1}" -f $Index ,$BackupDirs.Count
        Write-Progress -Activity $Text $status -PercentComplete ($Items / $SumMB * 100)  
        if ($File.Attributes -ne "Directory") {$count++}
    }
}
$SumCount+=$Count
$SumTotalMB="{0:N2}" -f ($Items / 1MB) + " MB of Files"
Logging "INFO" "----------------------"
Logging "INFO" "Copied $SumCount files with $SumTotalMB"
Logging "INFO" "$ErrorCount Files could not be copied"
 }


$Count=(Get-ChildItem $Destination | where {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"}).count
Logging "INFO" "Check if there are more than $Versions Directories in the Backupdir"

if ($count -lt $Versions) {

Create-Backupdir

} else {

Delete-Backupdir

Create-Backupdir
}


$CheckDir=Check-Dir

if ($CheckDir -eq $false) {
Logging "ERROR" "Mindenstens ein Ordner ist nicht verfuegbar, bzw. existiert nicht. Script beendet"
} else {
Make-Backup

$Enddate=Get-Date #-format dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss
$span = $EndDate - $StartDate
$Minutes=$span.Minutes
$Seconds=$Span.Seconds

Logging "INFO" "Backupduration $Minutes Minutes and $Seconds Seconds"
Logging "INFO" "----------------------"
Logging "INFO" "----------------------" 
}

Write-Host "Druecken Sie eine beliebige Taste um dieses Fenster sofort zu schliessen ..."
#$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

} else
    {
        $res = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Du hast auf Abbrechen gedrueckt. Willst du es nochmal versuchen oder das Skript beenden? ", "Speicherort fuer Backup waehlen", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel)
        if($res -eq "Cancel")
        {
            #Ends script
            return
        }
    }
}
$browse.SelectedPath
$browse.Dispose()
} Find-Folders
```

Comment: Put the returned value into a file or registry value and then check if that file or reg value exists before opening the dialog again?

Comment: Any other suggestions?